# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

`ngFor` isn't working in my app.

I split my app into separate modules and included `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';` into my child module and `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` into my `app.modules.ts` file, but I still get the following error.

```
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.
```

I have tried looking at other questions but all those just said to `include CommonModule`, which I am.

These are my files:

crud-list.component.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let item of cruds'>
      <td>{{item.OrderNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

crud-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudRequestService } from '@modules/crud/crud-services/crud-request.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crud-list',
  templateUrl: './crud-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crud-list.component.scss']
})
export class CrudListComponent {
  public cruds: Array<any>;

  constructor(private objService: CrudRequestService) {
    this.objService.get().subscribe(
      (oDataResult: any) => { this.cruds = oDataResult.value; },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }
}
```

crud.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CrudListComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud-list/crud-list.component';
import { CrudFormComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud-form/crud-form.component';
import { CrudComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: CrudComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: CrudListComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: CrudFormComponent },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: CrudFormComponent }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [CrudComponent]
})

export class CrudModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
/* all the imports */

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ForbidenAccessComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    AppHeaderComponent,
    AppFooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    BreadcrumbsService,
    AccordionService,
    ModalService,
    RequestService,
    IdentityProviderService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
/* imports */

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'crud', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => import('@modules/crud/crud.module').then(m => m.CrudModule)},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  // The error status pages
  { path: '403', component: ForbidenAccessComponent },
  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I can try. Never done it, tho.

Comment: I hadn't used stackblitz until a couple of months ago. It's perfect for demonstrating specific problems, and in your scenario it might help you see where you've gone wrong as you're copy code into a fresh project.

Comment: @KurtHamilton, can you add your own answer so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: Done. I've reverse engineered the solution, from your answer, but I thought it might be something like that anyway. Recreating your problem with minimum code generally helps you find some silly mistake :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I recreate your problem in a stackblitz I don't have an issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-60533597

Make sure that you add your components to the module `declarations` as well as to the `Routes`.

Answer (score 4):

crud.module.ts

```
//crud module should export crud component
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [CrudComponent],
  exports: [CrudComponent]
})

export class CrudModule { }
```

you may also be missing adding `CommonModule` in your `AppModule`'s `imports` array.

hopefully, this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks. @ traffic rn. will try it later and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. While the app was running with no other issues than the one stated, when I went to replicate the problem on StackBlitz, the code there gave me an error, telling me that I needed to add the `CrudListComponent` on my @NgModule declaration, so all I had to do was to add the component there, rebuild the app and it worked.

crud.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CrudListComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud-list/crud-list.component';
import { CrudFormComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud-form/crud-form.component';
import { CrudComponent } from '@modules/crud/crud.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: CrudComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: CrudListComponent },
      { path: 'create', component: CrudFormComponent },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: CrudFormComponent }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CrudComponent, CrudListComponent, CrudFormComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})

export class CrudModule { }
```

Comment: But this is already answered by @kurt-hamilton answer! This one should be accepted.

Comment: I know, if you look in the comments of the question, I tell him to give an answer to give him the bounty, as he helped me find the answer by making a stackblitz. I answered  to give a specific result before he put up his answer.

Comment: Thank you for finding the issue. This is the real answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with **Ionic 5** & **Angular 9** and searched for a solution for hours. Basically I identified **3 major reasons**.

**1. Clean & rebuild** (or re-install) your project.
Ionic 5 example: `cordova clean; ionic cordova build android` (or `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`) in project's dir.

**2.** Typically this is an issue with **CommonModule** not being included in your component's module (or **BrowserModule** not being included in your app's module). Ionic 5 example:

*list.module.ts*

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ListPage } from './list';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [ListPage]
})
export class ListModule {}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**3.** Depending what version of Angular you are running, if it has Ivy running, (likely not if you're using Ionic 5 currently) then you will need to have the **ModalComponent** in the **entryComponents** of the **parent module** as well as in the **declarations**. In the following example the CalendarModule shows the ListComponent as modal. Ionic 5 example:

*calendar.module.ts*

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...
import { CalendarPage } from './calendar';
import { ListPage } from "../../modals/list/list";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [CalendarPage, ListPage],
  entryComponents: [ListPage],
  providers: []
})
export class CalendarModule {}
```

P.S.: To de- & activate **Ivy** set Angular compiler options in TypeScript config in

*tsconfig.json*

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "enableIvy": false
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is present in the angular 9. I was using **angular(9.0.1)** version so upgraded to **~10.0.9** and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

What is NgbModule in the import of you app.module ? Because i kwow @NgModule but this don't need to be in imports:[...] but only imported at the top.

And some suggestions:
In crud-list.component.ts you need to unsubscribe your subscription and constructor is use for injection only, use ngOnInit ;)

```
export class CrudListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 cruds: Array<any>
 dataSubscription: Subscription

 constructor(private objService: CrudRequestService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscription = 
  this.objService.get().subscribe(data => {
   this.cruds = data.value
  })
 }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: NgbModuoe is the module for angular bootstrap. Sorry, but I didn't really understand the thing about imports. Can you explain a little further, please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue recently. You need to add **CrudListComponent** under **declarations** section of **CrudModule**. Please check if this resolves the issue for you.