# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item' in Ionic / Angular 9

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngfor

When trying to populate simple radio group list with phone numbers

Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'.

Issue is related to Angular 9. [Possible solutions](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&sxsrf=ALeKk03LXKqrfH65Pl1RjVx6zmPwJdjhCQ%3A1592865430636&ei=ljLxXoO7JsrJrgS8k7XwDA&q=Can%27t%20bind%20to%20%27ngForOf%27%20since%20it%20isn%27t%20a%20known%20property%20of%20%27ion-item&oq=Can%27t%20bind%20to%20%27ngForOf%27%20since%20it%20isn%27t%20a%20known%20property%20of%20%27ion-item&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJ1Dm_FRY5vxUYIKDVWgAcAB4AIABY4gBY5IBATGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiD3quRvpbqAhXKpIsKHbxJDc4Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) says that BrowserModule and Common module needs to be in place.
Think I got that.
Yet, error is still there.

[image]

Ionic info:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:
   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.2

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.0) : 0.6.0
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0)   : 0.2.8
```

add-number.page.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, ToastController, IonRadioGroup } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FirebaseAuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/user/auth_user.service';
import { PlayerDetailsModel } from '../../../../models';
import { FirebasePlayerService } from '../../../../services/firebase/players/firebase-players.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-number',
  templateUrl: './add-number.page.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './styles/add-number.modal.scss',
    './styles/add-number.shell.scss',
  ],
})
export class AddNumberPage implements OnInit {
  @Input() isModalRequired = false;
  @ViewChild('radioGroup') radioGroup: IonRadioGroup;

  public availableNumbers: string[] = [];
  // radioForm: FormGroup;
  //Get value on ionSelect on IonRadio item
  selected_number: any;

  constructor(
    private _modalController: ModalController,
    private _toastController: ToastController,
    private _playerService: FirebasePlayerService,
    private _authService: FirebaseAuthService
  ) {

  }

  radioGroupChange(event) {
    console.log("radioGroupChange", event.detail);
  }

  radioSelect(event) {
    console.log("radioSelect",event.detail);
    this.selected_number = event.detail;
  }


  public dismissModal() {
    this._modalController.dismiss();
  }

  private initalizeForm() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.availableNumbers.push("+16673039999")
    this.availableNumbers.push("+16673039998")
    this.availableNumbers.push("+16673039997")
  this.availableNumbers.push("+16673039996")

  console.log(this.availableNumbers)
  // this.selected_number = this.availableNumbers[0];

   }

}
```

add-number.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AddNumberPageRoutingModule } from './add-number-routing.module';
import { AddNumberPage } from './add-number.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    AddNumberPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AddNumberPage]
})
export class AddNumberPageModule {}
```

add-number.page.html

```
 <ion-content class="update-user-content">
    <section class="user-details-fields fields-section">

      <ion-list>

        <ion-radio-group  name="radio-group" allow-empty-selection="true" (ionChange)="radioGroupChange($event)"  #radioGroup>
          <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>Pick your TomLine phone number</ion-label>
          </ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let number of availableNumbers" (ionSelect)="radioSelect($event)">
            <ion-label>{{number}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start"  value="{{number}}" ></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>

    </section>
  </ion-content>
```

**Any idea how to fix this  ?**

.

Edit: https://pastebin.com/pVbFa6X3 app.module.ts

Comment: can you post the code of your app.module as well ?

Comment: reload your app first .... kindly kill the terminal and serve it again because your error clearly states that ngForOf is not a known property which makes no sense as you are not using any ngForOf and I also have tried your code of ts file and html ion-item it is working fine

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pVbFa6X3 <- app.module.ts

Comment: https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div/#.XvG6K3UzZbo kindly check your solution here if it works

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work for me

Comment: If I were you, I'd try enclosing the `ion-item` inside one `div` and do the `*ngFor` in the div. In other words, use a dummy `div` to go around the problem. Something like `<div *ngFor><ion-item></ion-item></div>`

Comment: @elnezah i got same error, so frustrating:

Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: That's strange. It looks like `ngFor` directive is not being properly loaded. In a quick look to your code all looks ok to me, but apparently it is not. I suggest you to search in this direction: why is ngFor not working in my Angular project. Take a look here for start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533597/cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-tr-in-angular-9

Comment: @Jalle Did you get a solution to this?  Seeing same thing here.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I assume that AddNumberPage is being leveraged as a modal somewhere in your app, but I cannot see where. Since you have placed this Modal within its own module, you have to import that module within the module from wherever your Modal is created from.

Answer (score 3):

Add the page to `app-routingmodule.ts`.

Comment: It worked! Do you know the explanation? I usually remove the modals from the routing app, I don't know why for one in particular it causes the error in the post if I don't put it back?